# starting ActivityB from ActivityA without returning to ActivityA

Tags: android

I'm trying to start **activityA** and in resume method of **ActivityA** I'm starting ActivityB using NEW_TASK and BRING_TO_FRONT. But it goes to **ActivityB** and comes right back to **ActivityA**.

If on the other hand I click on button in ActivityA and launch intent it goes to ActivityB just as expected!

What is the issue? Is it because I'm calling `startActivity(activityB)` inside resume method? What is the workaround, since I want to start my app with two activities running and get back to ActivityA when I am done with ActivityB?

One more thing, to create the intent I am using

```
  getPackageManager().getLaunchActivityEvent(packageName)
```

Comment: show more code please

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this:

```
public void onResume() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Your activity startup code here
            }
        });
}
```

What this does is put your activity startup code in the UIThread message queue, making it fire off after the resume code of the ActivityA has completed.

Comment: ok, does it need post delayed or anything? I'm trying it right now.

Comment: Simple post should do it, if it does not, try delayed with something like 100 ms.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to come back to Activity A when B finish then instead use (Different approach from yours)

```
StartActivityForResult(NextActivityIntent);
```

& do what ever you want on your return to Activity A in following method:

```
onActivityResult()
```

Answer (score 0):

Kelevandos suggestion will work, even without delay.

Just to give some less "hacky" alternative ...

Start activity B with `StartActivityForResult`. When doing so then onActivityResult is invoked. There you first check if it is returning from B (Just check the requestcode. Must be the same that you hand in). Even if B is the only activit that is invoked from A - this is just good practice.

And then call `finish()` on activity A.